# Simple angular example not working: ng-repeat + GET

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to iterate with ng-repeat, using data served from a REST service.

It works perfectly when the data is a single Json object, but when it comes to be a list of objects the HTML doesn't get the data.

Here is the code:

hello.js

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {
$http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://devfz.azurewebsites.net/api/providers' }).
    success(function (data) {
        $scope.providers = [data];
    }).
    error(function () {
        alert("Error");
    });
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/hello.js"></script>
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
</head>

<body role="document" style="padding-top: 70px; padding-bottom: 30px">
<div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div ng-controller="Hello">
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="min-width: 80px;">Id</th>
                    <th style="min-width: 80px;">Name</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="provider in providers">
                    <td>{{provider.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{provider.name}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much :)

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.providers = data;`?

Comment: Why brackets around `data` - `data` is probably already an array

Comment: Yes, I tried and it still doesn't work. I put the brackets for a test, but it doesn't work anyway. Thanks :)

Comment: I went to that url you have there -- looks like it's returning XML, not JSON. Angular does not natively handle XML APIs, only JSON ones

Comment: Thanks for your help, meshy. I went to this url using Chrome and it loads XML, but when i use Internet Explorer, it loads a JSON file. Is it normal?

Comment: Perhaps not. I expect that as this endpoint can change result formats, then it is likely to be returning the correct thing when it comes to a request from javascript.

Comment: I already solved it. About my last question, it is normal. There is an option in server to add XML formatting to the response if the browser request, but the response is still JSON. Angularjs, by default, requests JSON formatting, so that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your providers array contains a single element:

```
$scope.providers = [data]; // array containing a single element: data
```

If a JSON array is returned by the server, and you want to iterate over that array, then the code should be

```
$scope.providers = data;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The server returns a JSON array, so I removed the brackets and it still doesn't work. I modified this code to test the iteration:

`<tr ng-repeat="provider in providers">
    <td>Test {{provider.id}}</td>
    <td>Test {{provider.name}}</td>
</tr>`

Without brackets, the "Test" is not shown. With brackets, the "Test" is shown.

Answer (score 0):

after the controller definition make array providers

```
$scope.providers = [];
```

and in success callback concat data.

```
.success(data) {

    $scope.providers = $scope.providers.concat(data)
}
```